# How to calculate the gain and DC bias of the transistor circuit?

Tags: transistors, gain

[image]

Here is the circuit of T41-EP. How to calculate the DC bias of the transistor circuit, and the gain of this circuit?

More infomations:
[image]
[image]

Comment: What's the RF frequency? Is this supposed to be a wideband circuit? If so, over what band range? And, I guess, finally can you perform a KVL equation from this? At all?

Comment: Is there anything at all you can say about the transistor circuit's DC quiescent point, at all? Anything? Any simplifications that might be useful? Or is it a total mystery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully, you should be able to do the following for the DC biasing result. (Here, I will ignore the loading presented by \$Q_2\$, as it isn't terribly important.)

$$\begin{align*}
V_{_\text{CC}}-R_3\cdot \left[I_q\cdot\left(1+\frac1{\beta}\right)+\frac{V_b}{R_2}\right]-R_1\cdot\left(\frac{I_q}{\beta}+\frac{V_b}{R_2}\right)-V_{_\text{BE}}-R_4\cdot I_q\cdot\left(1+\frac1{\beta}\right)&=0\:\text{V}
\\\\
V_{_\text{CC}}-R_3\cdot \left[I_q\cdot\left(1+\frac1{\beta}\right)+\frac{V_b}{R_2}\right]-R_1\cdot\left(\frac{I_q}{\beta}+\frac{V_b}{R_2}\right)&=V_b
\end{align*}$$

From these two KVL equations you should be able to solve for \$I_q\$ and \$V_b\$.

It is really no more complicated than that. (You will need some assumed \$V_{_\text{BE}}\$, of course.)

Comment: how to choose the beta value?it is not the same with different collector current.

Comment: @armcc Agreed. And it's not the same, device to device, either. Or at different temperatures. And so on. However, it's not at all difficult to do a sensitivity analysis with respect to beta once you solve the DC operating point equations. Then you can vary beta and see how it impacts the DC quiescent point. A good design won't vary a lot.

Comment: @armcc In case it matters to you, I find from sensitivity analysis that the %-change in Vb is about equal to 0.0013216473 times the % change in beta. About one part per thousand, in short. So a 50% change in beta, at the local slope of your DC quiescent point, would mean less than a 0.07% change in Vb. Changing beta from 200 to 100 should result in a change from say about 1.188 V to about 1.187 V, for example. Not much to worry about in this case. You need to apply derivatives to get this value. But it's not hard, really.

Comment: the first KVL equations seems lost Iq.by the way if the RF is 3MHz~30MHz,gain is 6dB,how to design the amplifier circuits forward？

Comment: @armcc I don't know what "lost Iq" means, so I can't respond to that. I wrote about finding the DC quiescent point. I didn't add the AC gain analysis because, at the time, I had no idea where you were going. (But I may add it soon.) In your question, you asked for "DC bias" and "gain". You've now added more details and context, which is good (and would have been nicer still at the outset.) And here asking how to design wide bandwidth RF amplifiers suggests adding not only design and construction methods but is certainly more (and different) than what you started asking about.

Comment: \begin{align}V_{CC} -R3\cdot \left [ I_{q}\cdot \left ( 1+  \frac{1}{\beta }  \right )+  \frac{V_{b}}{R_{2}}   \right ] - R_{1}\cdot \left ( \frac{I_{q}}{\beta}+  \frac{V_{b}}{R_{2}}  \right )- V_{BE}- R_{4}\cdot I_{q}\cdot \left ( 1+  \frac{1}{\beta}  \right )= 0V  \end{align}

Comment: @armcc Oh. Got it. Thanks!

Comment: @armcc By the way, There isn't much excess gain in that amplifier stage to use as NFB. Icq is about 3 mA and the gain without NFB would be about (510/(68+8.7)) or about 6.65. Assuming the transformer driving this has very much lower impedance, the 390 Ohm resistor isn't going to be able to have much NFB impact. I'm curious about their work product to make that statement and if it includes details about what's driving the transformer.

Comment: The T41-EP is an  open source project, maybe it is design errors.

Comment: @armcc If I recall, there's some good material on RF amplifiers (broadband, in particular) in chapter 4 or 5 of *The ARRL Handbook for Radio Communications*. Construction details are also somewhere in that huge volume, as well. Do you have a copy to read?

Comment: @armcc Ah. Found it. The target I was pointing at in the ARRL handbook is section 5.4.4 "RF Amplifiers with Feedback". You want to get and read whatever is needed so that this section makes sense to you.

Comment: sorry i don't have the book.may be i need to purchase one.

Comment: @armcc [Here's a slightly fuzzy snapshot to gaze at](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORVF8.png). It is fair use, I believe.

Comment: thank you ,i got it.

Comment: @armcc I thought I'd provide [a slightly better version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KaDqY.jpg). Pay attention to the detailed differences shown in these examples with respect to the open source version you have. For example, look closely at Figure 5.39 and list out the differences. (A cap bypass across a bias resistor leading to Rf, for example. Or the way the emitter leg is set up. Not to mention the collector load arrangement. Construction details will also matter a great deal, too. (Dead-bug, manhattan style, etc.)

Comment: does the 8.7ohm means the internal emitter resistance rEE?I found a formula to calculator the rEE here:[Amplifier impedances](https://www.ibiblio.org/kuphaldt/electricCircuits/Semi/SEMI_4.html#xtocid903616)

Comment: @armcc Yes. At 3 mA, \$r_e^{\:'}=\frac{V_T}{3\:\text{mA}}\approx 8.7\:\Omega\$ at room temperature. This is the *dynamic resistance* and all that means is the local slope of the BJT I/V curve at its quiescent point. Just your basic first derivative slope thing.

Comment: assume \$V_{BE} = 0.65V \ and\  \beta = 100\$ ,i calculated the current  flowing through the emitter resistor R4 is about 7.2mA,about two times of the 3mA.

Comment: @armcc That's my mistake. I'm sorry about it and thanks for catching it! Here's what I compute from solution from the equations I provided, using \$\beta=200\$ and \$V_{_\text{BE}}=700\:\text{mV}\$: \$I_q=7.051762\:\text{mA}\$ and \$V_b=1.18192\:\text{V}\$. If I use \$\beta=100\$ and \$V_{_\text{BE}}=650\:\text{mV}\$ then I get: \$I_q=7.091046\:\text{mA}\$ and \$V_b=1.137013\:\text{V}\$. (You would expect \$V_b\$ to shift about \$50\:\text{mV}\$ if you change  \$V_{_\text{BE}}\$ by that same amount. Anyway, thanks. Sorry about the mistake.

Comment: @armcc Running LTspice to target beta 200 and vbe 700 mV, I get Iq=7.038 mA. Targeting beta 100 and vbe 650 I get Iq=7.076 mA. But, unfortunately, LTspice doesn't let me exactly set beta (or Vbe for that matter.) However, I arranged things so that it came out close.

Comment: @armcc So I think \$r_e^{\:'}\$ should be more like about 3.7 Ohms. So AC gain without NFB considered (and without Early Effect, either) would be 510/(68+3.7) or about 7.1.

Comment: I have the same result,by the way ,you can try to change the value of beta like this-[LTspice change beta](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=00LpZ0OeSv8),Best Regards

Comment: @armcc Yeah, you can change the model parameter BF. But it doesn't really give you what you think. Spice uses that as a basis. But it makes adjustments that you don't see. So the actual value is a little different. Also, you can use Isat (or Is) to change the Vbe. But again, this has to be tinkered with.

Answer (score 0):

Simplified circuit ...

One can have an higher gain than this.

[image]

[image]

Comment: thank you very much.I have the same simulator values.